# How few lines can javascript be on?

Tags: javascript, newline, minify

I am writing a little custom minifier for javascript, and I am wondering if I need to force line breaks after a certain number of characters on a single line, or if it matters at all?

For example, I can minify an entire script into a single line with thousands of characters, or every n characters, I could insert a line break (at an acceptable point in the js code) to drop it to the next line.

Is there a reason to do this, or is does javascript/browsers not care how many characters are on a line?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Other minifiers also put the produced JavaScript on one line. Just out of interest, why can't you use an existing minifier?

Comment: 1. It's a fun project, 2. I need to plug it in to my framework in such a specific way that I'd end up porting an existing one anyway. By looking at others and building my own, I get the port and the knowledge in almost the same amount of time :)

Comment: Ah right. I was almost expecting those answers actually! +1 for writing your own stuff :-)

Comment: Here's to reinventing the wheel!

Comment: Imagine if we'd just stuck with the first ever wheel design: "Yup, that's good enough" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an entire script on one line, it makes no difference to the parser.

However breaking content onto lines of about 4kB may be beneficial to the downloader, slightly improving performance.

Comment: What's the logic behind your second comment?

Comment: Adding line breaks to improve performance doesn't make sense in the slightest

Comment: Well, just going by what I've learned from socket functions in PHP. I could be wrong, though. Maybe it only applies to PHP socket functions and not to downloads in general.

Comment: I'm just curious...same question as paislee

Comment: @Kolink I get the idea behind the 4kB chunks for downloading, but wouldn't it be greatly variable on the encoding of the JS file?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't want to bet my site on various web servers, proxies, Internet Explorer, etc. all not-choking on *huge* line lengths. Of course, I don't know quite how I'd define *huge*, but jQuery - as an example - looks like it limits to about 512 characters per line. Put it this way, I'd prefer your minifier if it allowed me to choose whether I have line breaks every x characters or not.

Comment: Hmm good insight...I should definitely make it adjustable, and then set at a recommended length (even if it's "never")

Comment: You're suggesting that minified jQuery is only 512 characters per line?

Comment: I *was*. Having looked in more detail, I'll clarify that to about 1,000. Whatever the exact figure, it's certainly not all on one line, despite the fact that - as the other poster points out - it would be perfectly legal JS. I'm suggesting that the language is not the only limiting factor when you're transmitting files over the internet.

Comment: Between the line break after the license and the next break, I show around 32,404 characters. So if a widely used library like jQuery is willing to take that bet, I'd say its likely pretty safe.

Comment: Sorry, you're totally right - I was looking at a *way* old version of jQuery. BTW, looks like the *next* line in 1.7.1 is even longer :) I'll try to defend my general point by saying that it still seems sensible to at least offer an option, but I guess this 'proves' that there's no effective limit. Although it's interesting to note that jQuery *still* splits at a certain column, rather than minifying to a single line. I wonder why.

Comment: That's a good question. I know they used to use YUI Compressor. If they still do, the answer may be there.

Answer (score 2):

There are some pitfalls regarding to long lines of JavaScript.  The following is from the Closure Compiler's FAQ ([this link](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/faq.html#linefeeds)):

> ## Why are there random line feeds in compiled scripts?
>
> The Closure Compiler intentionally adds line breaks every 500 characters or so. Firewalls and proxies sometimes corrupt or ignore large JavaScript files with very long lines. Adding line breaks every 500 characters prevents this problem. Removing the line breaks has no effect on a script's semantics. The impact on code size is small, and the Compiler optimizes line break placement so that the code size penalty is even smaller when files are gzipped.